# Hello, TabWidget each tab refer to new xml

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-tabs, refer

I'm using Google's exmaple of [Hello, TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) but altered it to look like this:

main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView 
                android:text="@+layout/text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="this is another tab" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="this is a third tab" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

java file:

```
public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1").setContent(R.layout.text));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(R.id.textview2));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("TAB 3").setContent(R.id.textview3));

        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

and here is the text.xml in res/layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="This is Tab 1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What I'm basically trying to do is have each tab refer to its own xml file rather than all in main.xml, but the text in the first tab doesn't show up.

Comment: As you can see above the first tab in the java file, and the first <TextView in main.xml both refer to text.xml, but when I run the app, the first tab has no text and is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to have each tab refer to its own `Activity`? If so, you can set up an intent as the content for each tab:

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Test.class);       
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Of course, you'd then have to have a class named Test (or whatever else) that sets `test.xml` as the layout.

```
public class Test extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
    }
}
```

[This tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) will help you further if this is the type of scenario that you're trying to set up.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but no matter how many times I try, my app still force closes before it even opens, and yes I would like to make it so each tab refers to its own Activity.  Following your example and the one in the link you provided my app force closes. I even looked up instructions on creating a new activity but found no info on the android development site.

Comment: do you add your activities to the manifest? If you follow the tutorials line-by-line, try finding a simple project already completed and running that yourself to make sure something outside of your application isn't an issue

Comment: Actually I haven't been adding them to my manifest, while doing some research I discovered here: http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/ 
that adding them to the manifest is necessary.  Although going back to the android development site I wasn't able to find information as to how to add my particular Test Activity to the manifest, since it won't be a main launch item, but rather, in a tab.
p.s. Thanks for your help and patience thus far!

Comment: Check out this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html . It may be a bit overkill, but at the crux you need a line like `<activity android:name="ControllerActivity" android:label="ControllerActivity"/>` for every activity in your application.

Comment: I followed your advice, I discovered that I simply had to add:
<activity android:name=".Test"></activity>
to the manifest and it worked! I can't believe it took my that many hours with your help to figure out something so simple, but I'm pleased with the results.  Thanks again sahhhm!

Answer (score 0):

There's three options for tabs using the built-in tab host.

1. Multiple views on a single activity with one layout file
2. Multiple activities
3. Custom views built in a TabContentFactory

It sounds like you want #3. What you need to do is something like this:

```
setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
    public View createTabContent(String tag)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(HelloTabWidget.this).inflate(R.layout.text);
        // Setup the view here
        return view;
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> View view = LayoutInflater.from(HelloTabWidget.this).inflate(R.layout.text);
> ```

That's not quite right as LayoutInflater.inflate takes two parameters.